# C - take specific contents of an integer array and place them in another array

Tags: c, arrays, integer, primes

So, I have a large array called `allintegersarray` created already. It was created by taking a 2d array called matrix with rows being the first and columns being the second. I know how to find the prime numbers of the allintegersarray array, but I'm lost at how to copy these prime numbers to their own array, one i initiated called `primenumbersarray`. Here is some code;
first function:

```
int is_prime(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return 0;{
        if (num % 2 == 0 && num > 2) return 0;{
            for(int i = 3; i < num / 2; i+= 2)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                    return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and a second function:

```
void fillPrime(int A[TOTAL_ROWS][TOTAL_COLUMNS], int rows, int columns){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0 ;j < columns; j++){
             if(is_prime(A[i][j])){
                  allnumbersarray[arraylength++] = A[i][j];
              }
         }
      }
    ////////Below, this for statement will print the prime numbers within the array, 
but instead of doing that, I'd like it to fill the array called primenumbersarray////////

    printf("Prime numbers in all numbers array: \n");
            for (i = 0; i < arraylength; i += 2){
                printf( "%d\n", allnumbersarray[i]) ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the fillPrime , to something like this

```html
void fillPrime(int A[TOTAL_ROWS][TOTAL_COLUMNS], int rows, int columns){
int i,j; int a=0;
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(j = 0 ;j < columns; j++){
         if(is_prime(A[i][j])){
              primenumbersarray[a] = A[i][j];a++;
          }
     }
  }
```

so as i understood u want to save the prime numbers into an array called primenumbersarray , and all the number are already saved in a 2D array ( matrix )called A . i hope this helps , good luck .